# Store template class function pointers in map

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-pointers

**Template class**

```
template <class F>
class MyClass
{
public:

inline static bool isPresent()
{
    if (F::getDetails())
    {
        return F::isPresent();
    }

    return false;
};
};
```

**Base class**

```
class Base
{
public:

inline static bool isPresent()
{
    ...
}

static bool getDetails();
};
```

**Derived class**

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:

};
```

**Template class Function call**

```
const bool isEnabled = MyClass<Derived>::isPresent();
```

I would like to store the above function call as pointers in map. But, the template arguments could be different derived classes. How can I do it?

```
using MyClassPtr = bool (MyClass<Base>::*)();
map<string,MyClassPtr>  data;
data = {  
    {"abc", &MyClass<Derived>::isPresent},
    {"wer", &MyClass<Derived1>::isPresent}
};
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, bool (App::MyClass<App::Derived>::*)()>’ and ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’)
 data = {
```

Comment: `isEnabled` is not a function at all. what exactly you want? and please give [mcve]

Comment: @appleapple It's just some method in `MyClass`

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I believe I saw `const bool isEnabled` in question. and nowhere else.

Comment: I deleted my answer since someone downvoted without explaining why. If people here don't give a damn, then me too. Now I remember why I'm not that active. Regards.

Comment: static method is mostly *regular* functions, so `bool (*isEnabledFunc)() = &MyClass<Derived>::isPresent;`.

Comment: `isEnabled` is a typo. Updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your member function is static, you have to define the function pointer as a normal pointer type with:

```
using MyClassPtr = bool (*)();
```

The reduced complete code compiles for me:

```
class Base
{
    public:
        static bool isEnabled() { return true;}
};

class Derived: public Base { };
class Derived1: public Base { };

template <class F>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        inline static bool isEnabled()
        {
            return F::isEnabled();
        }

        bool AnyMember() { return true; }
};

template <typename T>
using MyMemberPtr = bool (MyClass<T>::*)();
using MyClassPtr = bool (*)();



int main()
{
    std::map<string,MyClassPtr>  data;
    data = {
        {"abc", &MyClass<Derived>::isEnabled},
        {"wer", &MyClass<Derived1>::isEnabled}
    };

    std::map<string, MyMemberPtr<Derived>> dataMember;

    dataMember = {
        {"xyz", &MyClass<Derived>::AnyMember}
    };

    std::map< string, std::function< bool() > > anyFuncs;

    anyFuncs =
    {
        { "one", [](){ return MyClass<Derived>::isEnabled();} },  // going to static
        { "two", [](){ return MyClass<Derived>().AnyMember(); } }, // going to member for Derived
        { "three", [](){ return MyClass<Derived1>().AnyMember(); } } // going to member for Derived1
    };
}
```

I assumed that `IsPresent` and `IsEnabled` is a typo.

Edit: Updated for member pointers.

The problem here is that it is not possible to have a pointer to "any" class type, so you have to define this as a template and use for each derived class a separate one.

If you have the need to store all and every pointer to a single data structure you can use `std::function` and lambda to solve that problem.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also mention how to do it for non-static functions?

Comment: If you could illustrate the solution using `std::function`, the answer would be complete and helpful to many